# Do IOS add x-requested-with header while requesting from UI WEB VIEW?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

Do IOS  add x-requested-with header while requesting from UI WEB VIEW ?
When you do the same from android app you can see that x-requested-with header is added to the request which has the app package name as value.

Comment: Hey have you found any info related to this?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple answers each of which that depends on the type of request.

Since UIWebView is retired I will answer based on WKWebView (using `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview') that is now available.

1. If your app is calling an `<img ng-src="https://example.com/imageFile.png">` then iOS does not attach any meaningful header information.  No `Referrer`, no `Origin` and definitely no `X-Requested-With`.  For Android, this same call does include both `Referrer` and `Origin`.
2. If your app is calling a `<ng-include src="https://example.com/somefile.txt">` then iOS does add the `Origin` header, but not the `Referrer` or `X-Requested-With`.    For Android, this same call does include both `Referrer` and `Origin`.

There are other examples of calling URLs that exhibit the behavior of #1 and #2 too.

3. If your app makes a `XMLHttpRequest` or `$HTTP.get()` calls, then iOS adds the `Origin` header but nothing else.  Android adds both `Referrer` and `Origin`

In all three examples, `X-Requested-With` is not natively passed.  This is because `X-Requested-With` can be spoofed (so can `Referrer`); which is probably why iOS does not natively include them with requests.  However, in example #3, you can create your own headers before making the http call - at which time you can add whatever you want EXCEPT `Origin`.  If you try to manually add `Origin` to overwrite the native one, both iOS and Android will spit out a warning and drop the manually added `Origin` part of the header.

We have implemented multiple security features on our api server.  One of which is lock down certain url paths so that only our app and our domain can access those paths and files.  This then forced us to rewrite parts of our app - any html page that used `<img ng-src="...">` had to be written to call a `$http.get()` call because then iOS natively included the `Origin` header.  Without, not passing any relevant header info (#1) caused our app to not be able to load images/files from that url path.

All of that being said, if you are needing `X-Requested-With` as some kind of (weak) security check on your server I would not go with `X-Requested-With`, instead use `Origin` to help validate the source of the request.  Custom browsers and custom code can still add their own `Origin` to spoof the origin (just as with X-Requested-With and Referrer) so don't rely on any of them for strong security.  Its still effective to have to help eliminate unwanted connections - but true hackers can get around that in with little effort.  Used in combination with other methods then helps make for strong security.

Last, specifically regarding `X-Requested-With` when manually set on iOS has issues.  We cannot rely on it because even though we see it being passed in the header, iOS is doing something to it that makes it unrecognizable by our server.  The code that injects `X-Requested-With` into our `$http.get()` calls on Android devices does get recognized by our server, but that same code on iOS does not get recognized by our server.  We have never been able to figure out why our server access (.htaccess) files see and match the `X-Requested-With` header from Android devices, but does not match on iOS.  All of our debugging spits out the full HEADER to console...and we see `X-Requested-With` and its value are correct, but for some reason the server doesn't make a match on it (for RewriteCond/RewriteRules) and denies the connection.

## UPDATE:

After much research, I finally found a solution.  Add `crossorigin="anonymous"` attribute to resource tags, this will force `Origin` into the header request.  See: [iOS standard http calls not passing specific headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75747493/ios-standard-http-calls-not-passing-specific-headers/75768027#75768027)