# iOS standard http calls not passing specific headers

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, http-headers

We are implementing certain security features on our api server.  Part of which is looking for specific HTTP headers like `Origin` and `X-Requested-With`.  When our app makes a custom call to our server it adds those specific headers to the request.  But other parts of our app just make standard http calls stuff like loading images: ie `<img src="https:mydomain.com/file/img1.png">`

The problem we have found though is that on iOS those two headers are omitted from the standard http call.  Is there anyway to force iOS to add `Origin` and/or `X-Requested-With` to resource loading calls?

Comment: you need to add part of the code, like are you using advanced http or http client or other http libraries..

Comment: Some one else had commented and said the same....I guess then deleted it. We found  In Cordova (AngluarJS), simply doing a `$http.get("https://example.com/file/img1.png").then(function(response) { ... }` passes the `Origin` header without having to actually add different headers.  From there we can add whatever we want.  But it now requires we rewrite all of our `<img ng-src="https://example.com/file/...">` to $http requests.

Comment: I think I had this issue long time ago. I think you can make a "global" origin inside the app as a setting for every request you make.

Comment: @RafA. - Can you elaborate on where/what that setting is?  In Cordova, for iOS/Android, setting `<preference name="hostname" value="myapp" />` then sets the `Origin` to `ionic://myapp` for iOS and `https://myapp` for Android - that is the only global setting I am aware of.  That being said, that has alwasy been set in my app, but the above issue persists on iOS - it looks good on Android.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a working solution.  In some HTML tags you can add `crossorigin="anonymous"` and that will force `Origin` into the header.

You can add this to certain tags - specifically resource loading tags - such as img, video, audio, link, and script are the tags that supports the crossorigin attribute.

`<img crossorigin="anonymous" ng-src="http://example.com/pics/someImage.png">`

```
GET /files/C1001/images/map_C1001_R1001_S1005.png HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/webp,image/avif,video/*;q=0.8,image/png,image/svg+xml,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
Origin: ionic://myapp
Host: portal.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
```

Without the `crossorigin` attribute, `Origin` is not added to the headers:

```
GET /files/C1001/images/map_C1001_R1001_S1001.png HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148
Accept: image/webp,image/avif,video/*;q=0.8,image/png,image/svg+xml,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Host: portal.example.com
```